# Error 40 edmx file MVC: The Type decimal(18,0) is not qualified with a namespace or alias

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, edmx

I am quite new to MVC concept. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and SQL Server LocalDb v11. So far I haven't had any problems. But then I changed a field for price in my database from real to decimal(18,0). I got an error regarding edmx file:

```
Error 40: The Type decimal(18,0) is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.
```

I've tried with type 'decimal' in my edmx file and also with int (just to see if it works), but still the same error.

I appreciate every answer.

Database part:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item] (
    [Id]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Description]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Price]      DECIMAL           NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [AuthorId]   INT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_ToDepartment] FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Item_ToAuthor] FOREIGN KEY ([AuthorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Author] ([Id])
);
```

Model class:

```
       namespace WebStore.Models

{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            this.Cart = new HashSet<Cart>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AuthorId { get; set; }

        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the part in edmx file where I get the error 40:

```
<EntityType Name="Item">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="DepartmentId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Description" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Price" Type="decimal(18,0)" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="AuthorId" Type="Int32" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Author" Relationship="Self.FK_Item_ToAuthor" FromRole="Izdelek" ToRole="Author" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Department" Relationship="Self.FK_Item_ToDepartment" FromRole="Izdelek" ToRole="Departmetn" />
      <NavigationProperty Name="Cart" Relationship="Self.FK_Cart_ToItem" FromRole="Izdelek" ToRole="Cart" />
    </EntityType>
```

Comment: Did you change edmx manually ?

Comment: Try <Property Name="Price" Type="Decimal" Precision="18" Scale="0" Nullable="false"/>

Comment: Yes, I had previously removed foreign key from some other table, but that time it worked ok.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it still doesn't work. Perhaps I'll need to revert changes and start again...

Comment: If you have access to Edmx Model Browser, try to update model from database again.

Comment: I don't have access anymore. I also tried with 'Run Custom Tool', but now effect. Is it possible to delete edmx and then create a new one (from the db) without any severe problems?

Comment: I don't think it would break anything

Answer (score 4):

If you are using decimal try to specify the type with a capital D like `Type="Decimal" Precision="18" Scale="0"` in the `edmx:ConceptualModels` section of the edmx file. The `edmx:StorageModels` section should be fine with `Type="decimal" Precision="18" Scale="0"`.